# make position:fixed DIV fit its parent container without javascript

Tags: css

Here is the code. I want the DIV.fixed-nav (position:fixed) to completely fit its parent DIV.container of which width may change. Is there a pure CSS solution for this?

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-width: 400px;
}

.fixed-nav {
    background-color: red;
    height: 20px;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99;
}

.content {
    background-color: green;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="fixed-nav">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Please check the [DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Ycf5G/).

Answer (score 0):

The problem with fixed is that it will always be relative to the browser window. So if you set 100% height on your fixed container it will be 100% of the browser window.

The only way I could think of to achieve this is to use jQuery. Or if you don't need the menu to be fixed and it could be absolute then height 100% will work.